# Unable to Save My.Settings DataTable

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

I am unable to save the contents of my DataTable "dtable" The scope of this Setting is USER, however although it saves it while the program is running. When I launch the program and re-load My.Settings.Sales_Mapping it is empty.

Can anyone help ?

```
    My.Settings.Sales_Mapping = dtable
            My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: likely because My.Settings does not have a DataTable type. A DataTable is an object, so it cannot be serialized (which is what Settings does), since it has no idea of what is in the DT it fails.  If it is in a DT where did the data come from?

Comment: Hi There,

It is set as a DataTable and it is coming from a DataGridView

    Dim dtable As DataTable =       CType(Me.SettingsDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable)

Comment: If it helps when I debug and close the Form, it jumps to Settings.Designer piece of code below:

` #If _MyType = "WindowsForms" Then
               If Not addedHandler Then
                    SyncLock addedHandlerLockObject
                        If Not addedHandler Then
                            AddHandler My.Application.Shutdown, AddressOf AutoSaveSettings
                            addedHandler = True
                        End If
                    End SyncLock
                End If
#End If `

Comment: A DataTable is an object.  an object cannot be serialized, just the information inside.  Settings has no idea what is inside.  *where did the data in the DT come from?*

Comment: I Created it like this ... '  Dim dt As New DataTable

            dt.Columns.Add("Site Code")
            dt.Columns.Add("Group Code")
            dt.Columns.Add("Nominal")
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 1, 1)


        My.Settings.Sales_Mapping = dt'

Comment: you could always use the `WriteXML` and `ReadXML` methods to save/load the data yourself.

Comment: can you use that and load into datagridview ?

Comment: of course.  the DGV binds to the data in the DT.  it has no idea where the data came from or how it was saved or loaded